# Obtener mac address en laravel 5.6

Tags: laravel

Quisiera saber si es posible obtener tanto la mac address del dispositivo que usa mi aplicación laravel, como el navegador con el cual acceden a la misma.  Por lo que he leído solo se puede obtener la mac address de mis dispositivos conectados a la red local, es ésto cierto?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Así es, no puedes obtener la dirección MAC a menos que el cliente y el servidor estén dentro de la misma LAN.

Para obtener el navegador, hay una librería muy buena que te permite hacer lo que quieres entre otras utilidades:

https://github.com/jenssegers/agent

Comment: **Muchas gracias por tu respuesta** La librería está buenísima!